# Why method is not defined, thous it is defined?

Tags: javascript

```
saveEvent = (eventId, event) => {};
saveEvent(eventId, event);
```

What is wrong here? I think I defined clearly the method.

[image]

Comment: `this.saveEvent()` - this is the way to call it in a class :)

Comment: [Pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) or of [exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) are not very helpful. Put a [mcve] and (if applicable) text of the exception in the question itself. The editor has buttons and [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to help you format it so it is readable. Provide a [live demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) if you're asking about HTML/JavaScript/CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Use `this` keyword to access the class fields/properties and methods.

**Example:**

```
class SomeClass {

    saveEvent = (eventId, event) => { };

    someOtherFunction = () => {
        this.saveEvent(eventId, event);
    }

}
```

Comment: Since the method is not a global function. You need to call the method in the class scope, which is `this`

Answer (score 0):

You missed to write ***this*** property and you are calling the saveEvent as a global function.

```js
this.saveEvent(eventId, event)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using OOP (classes) Then put the `this` keyword before executing the function

Like:- `this.saveEvent(eventId, event)`. And if not, please post the complete code here but don't take a screenshot! And I'm glad to help you